# Separate Numbers and Text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to separate the following types of data in 
Column A:
2814/1 BBx, 2814/1 BBSDS, 2885/3 BBC nn, 2585/3 COL BBC snnn

I want to seperate the Numeric and Text values into two different columns, but if the text contains "COL," I want to keep "COL" with the numeric portion. Using the example data, the expected results would be:

Column B as:  2814/1, 2814/1, 2885/3, 2585/3 COL
Column C as: BBx, BBSDS, BBC nn, BBC snnn

I have following code, but it is separating the source text into multiple columns and is seperating COL from the numeric portion.

```
Sub SepNum()
Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
For i = 1 To N
    ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), " ")
    k = 10
    For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        Cells(i, k).Value = ary(j)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are splitting on the *space* character, we must protect the *space* that precedes *COL*:

```
Sub SepNum()
    Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim s As String

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Replace(Cells(i, "A").Text, " COL", Chr(2) & "COL")
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(s), " ")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(ary(LBound(ary)), Chr(2), " ")
        s = ""
        For j = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
            s = s & " " & ary(j)
        Next j
        Cells(i, 3).Value = wf.Trim(s)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If *COL* has more than one *space* before it, then use:

```
Sub SepNum3()
    Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim s As String

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        s = wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text)
        s = Replace(s, " COL", Chr(2) & "COL")
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(s), " ")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(ary(LBound(ary)), Chr(2), " ")
        s = ""
        For j = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
            s = s & " " & ary(j)
        Next j
        Cells(i, 3).Value = wf.Trim(s)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Hi Garry, It's working but if we have two or more spaces in front of COL it is not??

Comment: @Kuma  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Garrys, Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all your text starts with BB? And there will only be 2 parts? You have spaces in there that you are trying to trim also but that aren't trimming and if they do, you won't end up with your sample output of BBC nn - you'd get BBCnn instead.
 So remove the array loop, split at BB and then put the BB back into the string.

```
Sub SepNum()
Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
For i = 1 To N
    ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), "BB")
    k = 10
    Cells(i, k).Value = ary(0)
    Cells(i, k + 1).Value = "BB" + ary(1)
    k = k + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Or if they don't all start with BB split at COL if it exists and readd it to the end of the number part of the string. If it doesn't exist split at the space and limit the split to 2.

```
Sub SepNum2()
Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
For i = 1 To N
    If InStr(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), " COL ") > 0 Then
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), " COL ", 2)
        ary(0) = ary(0) + " COL"
    Else
        X = wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text)
        Y = Cells(i, "A").Text
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "A").Text), " ", 2)'the 2 limits the split to the first space
    End If
    k = 10
    For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(i, k).Value = ary(j)
            k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Rodger, Second one works without any error. Thank you. I tried this formula to get the number but it is giving error                         Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H3").Value = "=LEFT(A3, FIND(" ", A3)-1)"?? Thank you.

Comment: If you are trying to use VBA to put a formula into a cell you would go with Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H3").Formula = "=LEFT(A3, FIND(" ", A3)-1)". instead of .value

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be using split if you are only wanting to divide the string at a single location, as this will split the string at every single space it finds.  Id recommend using `InStr()` to find the COL location (if it exists) for that case, and then also use `InStr()` to find the location where you should split it.

Also, if the form is always consistent (particularly that it is of form #### / #), then you can do more clever string work to accomplish this.  If it is always of that form, then my recommendation would be to first check if COL is in the string.  If it isn't found (`InStr` returns 0) then simply assign the values in B and C columns using the `Left()` and `Right()` String functions, knowing that it will always be split at the 7th value (again, assuming consistent number form).  If Col is found, then split the string from the 7 + 4 value

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, more flexible approach may be to use a `Regular Expression`. This allows you more flexibility in case your date layout changes, or new requirements are added, in the future.

Below is one example of a `RegEx` being encapsulated in a function that returns an array of matches. If there is no match, it simply returns "No match". It includes the optional `COL` all in the same pattern.

See if it helps you out.

```
Function ExtractVals(sInput As String) As Variant()
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim vMatch() As Variant
    Dim nCount As Integer
    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")

    With oReg
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d*/*\d*\s*(?:COL)?)\s(\w*)"
    End With

    If Not oReg.test(sInput) Then
        ReDim vMatch(0 To 0)
        vMatch(0) = "No Match"
    Else
        With oReg.Execute(sInput)(0)
            nCount = .submatches.Count - 1
            ReDim vMatch(0 To nCount)
            For i = 0 To nCount
                vMatch(i) = .submatches(i)
            Next i
        End With
    End If

    ExtractVals = vMatch
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim aMatches()

    aMatches = ExtractVals(Range("A1").Value)

    Range("B1").Resize(, UBound(aMatches) + 1).Value = aMatches
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Sub SepNum()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        fulllen = Len(Cells(i, 1))
        For j = 1 To fulllen
            If (Asc(Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)) >= 47 And Asc(Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)) <= 57) Or (Asc(Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)) = 44) Then
                numerals = numerals & Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)
            Else
                Text = Text & Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)
            End If
        Next j
        If InStr(Cells(i, 1), "COL") > 0 Then
            numerals = numerals & " COL"
            Text = Replace(Text, " COL ", "")
        End If
        Cells(i, 2) = numerals
        Cells(i, 3) = Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

[image]